# Getting Permission issue while running flutter app to real device

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am getting permission issue while installing flutter app to real device

> Logs

Exception: null. The flutter tool cannot access the file.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

> Flutter Doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Linux, locale en_IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: What device do you using?

Comment: samsung galaxy M30s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the permission of the flutter SDK folder and the permission of your project folder.